# Logical error with input validation in c++

Tags: c++, validation

The following code contains a logical error
every time i run it and enter 1 or 0 the code
in the while loop is still executed.
can someone tell me why?

```
bool getmove()
{
    bool move;
    cout << "Would you like to make the first move?(1 for yes 0 for no)\n";
    cin >> move;
    while(move != 1 || move != 0 || !cin.good())
    {
        if(!cin.good())
        {
            cout << "ERROR please try again\n";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(80,'\n');
            cin >> move;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid input please try again\n";
            cin >> move;
        }
    }
    return move;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
while(move != 1 || move != 0 || !cin.good())
```

It will *always* be the case that `move != 1 || move != 0` (because it can't be both).

Furthermore, you'll avoid some trouble by reading in something like a string and testing that, rather than relying on casting.

Comment: Thank you so much i dont know how i missed that. i could do: while((move != 1 && move !=0 ) || !cin.good)

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to write a function which can validate the input of a boolean value, your code can be simplified to:

```c
bool getmove()
{
    bool move;
    cout << "Would you like to make the first move?(1 for yes 0 for no)\n";
    while (!(cin >> move))
    {
        cout << "Invalid input please try again\n";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(80, '\n');
    }
    return move;
}
```

It is important to realize that `while (!(cin >> move))` will repeat the loop until a valid boolean value can be read from the console and written into `move`.